# pandas plot two variables using character

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, plot

I am trying to plot two variables fdr_new and fdr_old with different characters and color blue and o for fdr_old red and x for fdr_new below is what I have tried I do not see any red and x on my plot not sure what I am doing wrong (pasting only df.head())

df :

```
df = pd.read_csv('~/plot.txt', sep='\t')
df.head()
id1 fdr_new fdr_old
a   0.025673    0.004912
b   0.098444    0.002133
c   0.00003 0.000004
d   0.330957    0.302002
e   0.939168    0.932705
```

code:

```
coff.plot(x='fdr_new', y='fdr_old', style=['bo','rx'])
```

plot using code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'
rd = pd.read_clipboard()
rd.head()
        id1 fdr_new fdr_old
0   a   0.025673    0.004912
1   b   0.098444    0.002133
2   c   0.000030    0.000004
3   d   0.330957    0.302002
4   e   0.939168    0.932705
rd.plot(x = 'id1', y = ['fdr_new','fdr_old'], style=['bo','rx'])
```

[image]

changing color:
[image]

after close and halt:
[image]

changing style did the job along with removing the import 'retina' command.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a scatter plot where each point is coordinate pair consisting of one part from `fdf_new` and the other part from `fdr_old`.  No point on this plot is from only `fdr_new` or `fdr_old`.  Because your `fdr_old` is specified as your y-axis it is assumed as the series name and thats why you see it in the legend.  But only the first style is used... because you only have one series of points.

The only way I can see to reconcile what I think you are trying to do is to treat `fdr_old` and `fdr_new` as separate timeseries.

```
df[['fdr_old', 'fdr_new']].plot(style=['bo', 'rx'])
```

[image]

You can even put `id1` in the x-axis

```
df.set_index('id1').plot(style=['bo', 'rx'])
```

[image]

Comment: no matter which method I try I do not see two data points I have posted the plot in main body

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: pd.__version__ `u'0.19.2'`

Comment: @sbradbio Hmm... I switched to `0.19.0` and it still works for me.

Comment: @sbradbio your next step is to provide a complete example that reproduces the problem.  I can't spend my time guessing.

Comment: sorry I just used the code as is on my data set only difference is i have 87 rows could you please guide me what would you like me to share

Comment: I have added the data set as to main body

Comment: We refer to it as a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and its expected to be code that I can easily copy and paste into my IDE or environment and run.  If you provided a good **MCVE** then I should be able to see your problem right away.  It acts to remove any ambiguity.  So I don't spend time questioning what your datatypes are, how many columns you have, and what not.  If we can't solve your problem given an **MCVE**, then we can deduce the problem is based on versions.

Comment: I have filtered my question, and even with the data i posted the first time I could not get the same plot

Answer (score 3):

You can use multiple Y-axis parameters

```
df.plot(x = 'id1', y = ['fdr_new','fdr_old'], style=['bo','rx'])
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting the plot so its some issue thats not with the code in itself. May be try changing the style=['bo','rx'] to style=['bo','gx'] to see if it prints a x with a different color?

Comment: changed it.. no success..please see plot in main with color changed

Comment: I could finally reproduce the error. The import %config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina' seems to be causing the error, see the issue reported on github here:https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8468

Comment: I restarted the environment just to cross-check and I am able to see the red crosses without importing %config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'

Comment: restarted kernel on jupyter notebook with out the 'retina' command still no luck :( posted plot after restart

Comment: Did you close and halt? I closed the notebook the first time and opened - it didnt work. Second time I used closed and halt in File dropdown menu and then restarted my file, it did.

Comment: yes i did close and halt still issue persists, move to ggplot in R?